# What is `process.binding('fs')` in `fs.js`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I see in top of the `fs.js` there is a `process.binding('fs')`.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L10:

```
const binding = process.binding('fs');
```

And then, it's used as:

```
binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
           stringToFlags(flag),
           0o666,
           req);
```

(In https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L303-L306)

My question is:

- What does `process.binding('fs')` mean?
- What's `fs` here (We already in `fs.js`)?
- Where can I find the source code of `binding.open`? Is it Javascript code or c/c++ code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. `process.binding()` is an internal API used by node to get a reference to the various core C++ bindings.
2. `'fs'` in `process.binding('fs')` is a reference to the *C++ binding* ([`src/node_file.cc`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b488b19eaf2b2e7a3ca5eccd2445e245847a5f76/src/node_file.cc) in the node source tree) for the `fs` module.
3. As mentioned, `process.binding()` references C++ bindings, so in this case `binding.open()` is exported [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b488b19eaf2b2e7a3ca5eccd2445e245847a5f76/src/node_file.cc#L1465) and defined [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/b488b19eaf2b2e7a3ca5eccd2445e245847a5f76/src/node_file.cc#L982-L1009).